# Move package from Android manifest to build files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My Android Studio claims that declaring the package in the manifest like this is deprecated:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="this.is.my.package">
```

The error message is:

> Move package from Android manifest to build files

> Declaration of a project's namespace using the package attribute of the Android manifest is deprecated in favour of a namespace declaration in build files.

But the button "Run selected steps" is disabled and I cannot click it.

How to fix this error message?

Answer (score 24):

leave this line in there, thats an old, "legacy" way from times when there were no Gradle used in Android projects... it's still used for generate `R.*` references for resource files

current times and Gradle-based projects: declare an `applicationId` and `namespace` in your gradle files (e.g. with same value `"this.is.my.package"`). some DOC in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module), some sample below:

```
android {
    namespace "this.is.my.package"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "this.is.my.package"
        ... rest of code
```

Comment: thanks, I had to leave the package entry, otherwise android stopped finding its R files in its auto generated stuff

Comment: GPT-4 is hard on your heels with an extremely structured explanation, but insists on MOVING the line instead of ADDING it. It uses the right syntax though in build.gradle.  

Q:  
in android studio upgrade prerequisites is disabled due to the error
"Move package from Android manifest to build files"
there is a line
package="androidx.media3.demo.main">
to which file and where do i exactly move this and does the syntax change?  
  
GPT-4:  
The package attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml file should be moved to your build.gradle file, specifically to the android block...